# Using <q> element when referring to elements of a page in text

Tags: html, xhtml, coding-style

In a web app's help/instructions and error message we often need to refer to parts of a page.

Example: Enter your message in the "body" field.
Example: The "body" field's content cannot exceed 250 characters

**Question**: in terms of html markup, would it make sense to use the `<q>` element for the "body" word above? What would be the semantically correct markup to use?

```
Enter your message in the <q>body</q> field.
The <q>body</q> field's content cannot exceed 250 characters
```

Looking for opinions, suggestions.

Notes:

- Don't care about the use of quotation marks, I want something that is semantically correct, i.e. it give the right meaning.
- Would like a simple tag that a tech writer/translator could easily deal with.
- Would like to avoid `<span class="something">body</span>` as it is long and give no semantic meaning to its contents.
- Found this:

  > When referring to a word’s form rather than its meaning, use quotation marks to draw the reader’s attention
  >   http://termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect8&info0=8.11#zz8

**Conclusion**

Going to go with the good old `<span class="reference">body</span>`. I guess I was wishing for an html tag for something like "text references". Thanks for the feedback.

Marc

Comment: Note that `<q>` means "This is a quotation" *not* "This should be wrapped in quote marks". (The spec requires that such quotations be wrapped in quote marks, but that is an implementation detail).

Comment: It seems you are looking for the HTML5 <mark> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont think it would.
It would help if you'd had an actual quote.

A field name is not really a quote. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Well, I am "referring" to something in the page by its label. As a reference, the q html element was the closest I could find... But I agree it doesn't quite feel right, which is why I asked the question...

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if you're referring to an `input` field, I'd suggest using a `label` element:

```
<span class="errorMessage">Please enter information in the <label for="body">body</label> field.</span>
<!-- other content -->

<label for="body">body</label>
<input type="text" id="body" name="body" />
```

I'm not sure, but I get the impression that you considered using a `q` because you were using quotes as an aesthetic/presentational choice, but it's not a quote, which removes the semantic argument for using a `q` element. If you want to use quotes, you can use CSS:

```
.errorMessage label:before,
.errorMessage label:after {
    content: '"';
}
```

Comment: Regarding the label element, this use seems to go against its intended use (within forms), but otherwise would make sense.

Comment: The only semantic use for a `label` is to *label* an `input` element, and (in most browsers) moves focus to that labelled element. Routinely the label appears in a `form`, but that's because, routinely, that's where the `input` itself appears.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with akond.

Consider using one of this tags `<em> <strong> <dfn> <code> <samp> <kbd> <var> <cite>` or `<span>` tag with a specific class attribute. I would prefer the latter.

Comment: -1 for suggesting a list of (mostly) wildly inappropriate elements.